# how to draw the line in middle of every bar

Tags: rgraph

Is there any chart available as below in RGraph or Swimlane ngx charts.

[image]

if it is not available Please let me know how to do it.
Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain the line please?

Comment: bar values will be fixed for all but the black line will change you can refer https://bdb.ai/automotiveDashboard